Use shortcut in Safari search bar to visit website
Is there a Safari-native way to use a kind of "shortcut" in the search bar to go directly to a website?
For instance, to go directly to the Python Pandas GitHub issues page, I would like define a shortcut that allows me to just type ghpd (or similar) in the search bar, press return and be directed there.
I know that the xSearch for Safari extension offers this ability, if the `Enable Empty Searches" option is configured... but I would prefer not to use a third-party extension for this.


You can use the MacOS Text Replacement in the Settings > Keyboard > Text Replacements... and add an entry for "ghpb" and the link.
Text Replacement Mac
And then when you type ghpb, it asks to replace with the link.
You just have to type down arrow and enter.
gdbh replacement
Apple : https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/replace-text-punctuation-documents-mac-mh35735/mac

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
